# Цикл while как сделать чтобы цикл выполнил одно действие один раз а остальные выполнял несколько?

Tags: java

Как сделать чтобы после ввода имени в цикле снова не выводилась строка **Введите имя** ?
Введите имя
Барсик
Введите "exit"
**Введите имя**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);  
while (true){  
   String d = "Введите имя";  
    System.out.println(d);  
    String st = s.nextLine();  
    System.out.println("Введите /"exit/"");  
    if (st.equals("exit"))  
        break;  
}

} 


}
```

Comment: System.out.println("Введите имя");  вывести из цикла и поставить до while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы попробуйте разобраться как у Вас код работает:

`String d = "Введите имя"`
`System.out.println(d);` - тут все понятно, но я бы написал так: `System.out.println("Введите имя: ");`
`String st = s.nextLine();` - тут вы читаете код с консоли и записываете в переменную `st`
`System.out.println("Введите /"exit/"");` - тут все понятно
`if (st.equals("exit"))` - и вот тут внимание, вы сравниваете `st` с `"exit"`, но сейчас там просто имя введенное ранее, условие не выполняется и цикл начинается по новой, и появляется `"Введите имя"`
Можно сделать так:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String d = "Введите имя";
            System.out.println(d);
            String st = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите exit");
            String ex = s.nextLine();
            if (ex.equals("exit"))
                break;
        }
```